# H264 encoder for silverlight webcam capture

Tags: silverlight, video, encoding, h.264

I was hoping to capture and save webcam video using silverlight but it appears Silverlight does not have any coded and its unto developer to find encoders and encode frames.

Know any reliable encoders free/paid which works well?

Comment: I would like to know this too